# Unit tests parallelization is different if executed from Windows or CentOS

Tags: .net-core, windows-10, centos7, xunit

I am developing a simplified ORM in .NET Core 2.2 and I wrote some xUnit unit tests that aim to test a SQL Server database creation/deletion or the basic CRUD actions. I'm on Windows 10 and I have a CI environment also running on Windows 10. However, I recently added a CI environment on CentOS 7 on a server in order to check that my development is really working on different OS thanks to the .NET Core Framework.

The problem I encountered is that I poorly designed my unit tests and they are concurrents. Thus, I have tests that are trying to do some CRUD actions in parallel to a test testing the database deletion functionality, leading to a `A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server` error.

What is really strange is that I can execute this tests as many times as I wish on my local environment (Windows 10) or my Windows 10 CI environment, it will never fail. Also, if I change the connection string to connect my local (Windows 10) unit tests to the remote database hosted on the CentOS environment, it also passes. BUT, when my test are runned by my CentOS CI runner or when I run then manually while connected in SSH to my CentOS server it always fails. Note that, when ran from Windows 10 with Visual Studio, I can enable the `Run Tests In Parallel` option from the tests explorer, tests always pass and don't seem to be parallelized. Also, I don't have any xUnit specific configuration file so I'm using the default configuration in both environments.

I'm not asking to help me fix my unit tests, I'm asking to understand why it seems that my tests are not executed in parallel on Windows 10 while it seems to be executed in parallel when ran from CentOS. Could it be a problem from Windows not doing its parallelization job?

Any help is welcome. Thanks.